# Named pipe wrapper, usage over network

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have an working implementation of how two form applications and use named-pipe-wrapper v1.5.

Connection like this on server:

```
server = new NamedPipeServer<string>("named_pipe_test_server");
```

Connection like this on client:

```
client = new NamedPipeClient<string>("named_pipe_test_server");
```

now i have my server on another computer, same network. 
how do i adress this. 
I want to type like,

```
client = new NamedPipeClient<string>("//192.168.100.2//named_pipe_test_server");
```

is this possible ? in this case, what is the syntax ?

Comment: it might have worked if the string was listed as @""//192.168.100.2/named_pipe_test_server"

Comment: @BugFinder: there's no need to use `@` for forward slashes (i.e. `'/'` characters). However, the OP may want to remove the second forward slash between the IP address and the pipe name.

Comment: good point - they should be \ which is why my brain was on it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NamedPipeClientStream(String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355390.aspx) overload to specify the name of the remote computer.

```
client = new NamedPipeClientStream("192.168.100.2", "named_pipe_test_server");
```

Comment: This is not a part of named-pipe-server v1.5.
Can i still use it.

Answer (score 0):

In named-pipe-server you can specify the server name as the second parameter to NamedPipeClient.

```
private readonly NamedPipeClient<string> _client 
  = new NamedPipeClient<string>(Constants.PIPE_NAME,"SPAN24");
```

You must use the Computer name not it's IP address.

You need to get the source from Github. 
https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper
The second parameter is not available in the Nuget package.